# Cancel Draw issue

Tags: flutter, github-issues

The following error is appearing no.of times can anyone brief about this

I/ViewRootImpl@c367172MainActivity: [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@8985646  isViewVisible: true

Solution for the issue